# Conditional innerhtml change

Tags: javascript, html, dom, opera

Let's say I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<li id="jkl">                                 
  <div class="aa">                         
    <div class="bb">                                 
      <div class="cc">                                                 
        <div class="dd">                             
          <a ...><strong>                            
              <!-- google_ad_section_start(weight=ignore) -->Test                             
              <!-- google_ad_section_end --></strong></a>
        </div>                                     
      </div>                                           
    </div>                         
    <div class="ee">                                                         
      <div class="ff">                                                      
        <div class="gg"> 
          <div class="excludethis">                          
            <a...>Peter</a>                                                 
          </div>                      
        </div>                                           
      </div>                           
    </div>                   
  </div>                
</li>
```

My goal is to set the content(innerhtml) of `<li id="jkl">` to '' if inside of `<li id="jkl">` there is any word of a list of words(In the example below, Wortliste) except when they are in `<div class="excludethis">`.

In other words, ignore `<div class="excludethis">` in the checking process and show the html even if within `<div class="excludethis">` there are one or more words of the word list.

What to change?

My current approach(that does not check for `<div class="excludethis">`)

```
Wortliste=['Test','Whatever'];

TagListe=document.selectNodes("//li[starts-with(@id,'jk')]");
for (var Durchgehen=TagListe.length-1; Durchgehen>=0; Durchgehen--) 
{
    if (IstVorhanden(TagListe[Durchgehen].innerHTML, Wortliste)) 
    {
        TagListe[Durchgehen].innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

with

```
function IstVorhanden(TagListeElement, Wortliste) 
{
    for(var Durchgehen = Wortliste.length - 1; Durchgehen>=0; Durchgehen--) 
    {
        if(TagListeElement.indexOf(Wortliste[Durchgehen]) != -1) 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Only has to work in opera as it's an userscript.

Comment: If you want to know whether a string *starts* with a certain substring, compare against `0` (`=== 0`) instead of `!= -1`. The latter basically means *if the substring is contained anywhere in the string*.

Comment: For reference, that `selectNodes` stuff doesn't work in Chrome.  I'm not sure it'll work in any browser outside of IE.

Comment: @cHao In works in the browser I want it to work

Comment: @FelixKling Does that solve my problem or is it just a subtlety?